# PowerShell won't sort an array of objects

Tags: powershell

Why won't PowerShell (v5) sort this array of objects by key?

```bsh
'[{"key":"f5"},{"key":"f1"},{"key":"f8"}]' | ConvertFrom-Json | sort key
```

```
key
---
f5
f1
f8
```

Other variations tried include `... | Sort-Object -Property {$_.key}`

Answer (score 5):

The answer is that, when piping data directly, each object arrives separately and individually to the Sort-Object cmdlet and it just spits it out.

The solution is to pass the entire array to Sort by using brackets:

```bsh
('[{"key":"f5"},{"key":"f1"},{"key":"f8"}]' | ConvertFrom-Json) | sort key
```

```
key
---
f1
f5
f8
```

Comment: Hmmm... this looks a bit like reputation farming if you ask a question and post the answer within the same minute..

Comment: To be honest, I found the answer while formulating the question and there's always the option to self-answer so I'm trying it out. I had a real question which neither google nor stackoverflow's search was answering (at least not as I had formulated it). Never seen a harvest of this reputation farming of which you speak ;-)